# How to make public methods only visible in class itself and class owning the object in C#?

Tags: c#, methods

My colleague and I came across this when looking into getting the invocation list of a delegate. If you create an event in say class X, then you can access the public methods of the event fine from within that class. But (and please ignore stuff like why you'd have public access to class members, this isn't what we're asking!), if we have a class Y instantiating X, and accessing the event within X, it can't call any of the public methods such as GetInvocationList() of the event. We wanted to know how this works. Here is a code sample (read the comments to see what we mean):

```
    public class X
    {
        public delegate void TestMethod();

        public event TestMethod testMethod;

        private void rubbish()
        {
            // can access testMethod.GetInvocationList() fine here
            testMethod.GetInvocationList(); 
        }
    }

    public class Y
    {
        public Y()
        {
            X x = new X();
            x.testMethod += this.test;

            // here it says testMethod can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=
            // why is this? (i.e. the below line is invalid)
            x.testMethod.GetInvocationList(); 
        }

        public void test()
        {
        }
    }
```

Out of curiosity how do you achieve this, and what's the reason for having this feature avaialble?

Many Thanks 
 Amit

Comment: Are you asking "how could I accomplish the same thing for my own class", or "why are events designed that way"?

Comment: Are you asking how do you emulate this behaviour for other public members or how to fix the code you posted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what the `event` keyword does; it is a modifier that restricts operations other than subscription to the owning class. If you remove the `event` keyword you will end up with a plain delegate that clients outside the class can call e.g. the `GetInvocationList()` method on.

In a [blog post](http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000040.html) they compare the generated IL code for a plain delegate and an event and it is handled exactly the same. The `event` keyword is a compile-time modifier that restricts access to the methods of the delegate. (It also enables use in interfaces). All the details are in the blog post.

Comment: Thanks Anders! I'll read the blog and come back with any further questions (e.g. is this something we can do for our own methods or there is some magic going on when the event keyword appears?)

Comment: @user555265 It'll be baked into the compiler, but there might be some post-processing fun you can do to get things to occur at runtime. The code here allows people to place constraints on enums and delegates, not the same task but maybe the same solution, so might be worth reviewing: http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

Answer (score 1):

I found some info on this - the access to this outside of the declaring class is very restricted - below is from MSDN site ([Events tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

> Invoking an event can only be done from within the class that declared the event. Hooking up to an event from outside the class
> that declared it, an event looks like a field, but access to that
> field is very restricted. The only things that can be done are:
>
> Compose a new delegate onto that field.
>
> Remove a delegate from a (possibly composite) field.
>
> This is done with the += and -= operators. To begin receiving event
> invocations, client code first creates a delegate of the event type
> that refers to the method that should be invoked from the event. Then
> it composes that delegate onto any other delegates that the event
> might be connected to using +=.

More info is available at the link.

Answer (score 0):

afaik it's when using events only, if you remove the "event" in the line you could use the method just fine

Answer (score 0):

**Think of delegates separately from events**

hmmm... I'm going to take a WAG here.

Put your delegate declaration in your namespace, outside of any classes.

- In Class X, create an instance of that delegate (never mind the event) and register
  "handlers:" (i use that term loosly) as desired.
- Create a public method or property so Class Y can get (a reference
  to) the delegate, and hence it's invocation list.
- Now you can do whatever you want in Class Y. You can even create a
  "mirror" event in Class Y, using Class X's delegate invocation list.